# Importando arquivos sem nomenclatura com NodeJS

Tags: node.js, import

Estou criando uma estrutura de arquivos em uma aplicação onde cada diretório contém um arquivo "index". Esse arquivo index leva o nome do meu diretório para melhorar a legibilidade. Ex:

```
foo
|--foo.js    // <- index
|--bin.html
|--bar
|  |--bar.js // <- index
   |--bin.html
```

Com isso, a estrutura que será utilizada para um `require()` ao fazer a importação de qualquer arquivo sempre será algo do tipo

```
const foo = require('./foo/foo');
const bar = require('./foo/bar/bar');
```

Eu procuro alguma maneira de criar um arquivo sem a nomenclatura, e que o NodeJS entenda para a importação, seria algo do tipo:

```
foo
|--.js // <- sem nome = arquivo da pasta
|--bin.html
```

Assim eu poderia trabalhar com arquivos semelhante a namespace's...

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso com NodeJS?

Comment: No caso de `|--.js // <- sem nome = arquivo da pasta` como queres fazer o `require`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `foo/index.js` e `require('./foo')` (isso é mais prudente e bem comum). Ou você pode adicionar um `package.json` no diretório `foo` e dar qualquer nome para o `main`.

eg.

*foo/package.json*

```
{"main": "qualquer-coisa.js"}
```

*main.js*

```
require('./foo') // vai dar require em './foo/qualquer-coisa.js'
```

O algoritmo completo está em: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules

Mas **não faz isso**, não vai muito com as convenções.

**Melhor só fazer**

```
foo
|--index.js
|--bin.html
```

---

```
require('./foo')
```